# I want to make header image disappear on scrolling and nav bar to stick to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make header disappear on scrolling and nav bar to stick to the to of the page.

```
<div class="headerimg">
  <!-- image that will disappear when scroll -->
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <!--navbar to stick to the top when image disappear -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `scroll` event to do these tasks. Here I am using 2 `div`s with `class` `.red` and `.green`. I will hide the `.red` `div` and stick `.green` div at the top on scroll.

**Example:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
// Listen to scroll event for window
$(window).scroll(function(){
     $(".red").hide(); // Hide the red div
     $(".green").addClass("stick"); // Stick the green div at top
});
```

Here is the [demo](https://jsbin.com/hefece/edit?html,css,js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Scroll Event and Scroll Stop Events. For hiding and showing header as u have given.
So,

```
        $(document).on("scroll",function(){
        $('.headerimg').hide(); });

        $(document).on("scrollstop",function(){
        $('.headerimg').show(); });
```

Jquery inbulit function Hide/Show internally append style Display:None and removes Display none(ie makes it as initial),If we use Display : none property the 'navbar' will occupy the 'headerimg' space. Or else if u want retain the header space and stil hide the header contents, you can directly use vissible: none property.

Thank you